# Mongo find records where key exists when the key is of type ISO Date

Tags: mongodb

I'm using ISODates as keys to make my data structure more compact, i.e.:

```
{ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"): <value>}
```

Instead of:

```
{thing: {
  when:ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  value: <value>
}}
```

Now I want to find all records that contain a specific date-as-key, as in:

```
db.collection.find({ ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z") : {$exists: true}})
```

But this returns the error:

```
E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

And this is fine:

```
db.collection.find({ any_key_that_is_not_a_date : {$exists: true}})
```

Answer (score 0):

The keys in a document are strings. Any UTF-8 character is allowed in a key, with a few notable exceptions:

> 1) Keys must not contain the character \0 (the null character).This
>   character is used to signify the end of a key.
>
> 2) The . and $ characters
>   have some special properties and should be used only in certain
>   circumstances, as described in later chapters. In general, they should
>   be considered reserved, and drivers will complain if they are used
>   inappropriately.